# What causes this Visual C++ Debug Error for asio server example？

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio, stdthread

## Update:

I am going to use detach since my plan is to shut down the application, so I don't need join.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

### Original question

I am following the asioref-1.10.6 example for the TCP server with asynchronous mode.  I don't have boost, so I am using C++11 std thread to allow both server and client working in same project.

I encountered this error:

```
Debug Error! ... abort() has been called ) Press Retry to debug the application. Abort/Retry/Ignore
```

What I did:

1. I put server example in a function asynServe()

   ```
   asio::io_service io_service;
   tcp_server server(io_service);
   backService = &io_service;
   io_service.run();
   ```
2. put a main function, so it will wait for the client thread to finish.

   ```
   std::thread t1(asyncServe);
   std::thread t2(asyncClient);

   t2.join();
   tryshutdown();
   //t1.join();
   int a;
   std::cin >> a;
   ```
3. Put a shutdown function which just calls backService->stop();  I want to stop the server thread when the client finishes the job.

What happened is if I don't have t1.join() in the main, the Abort/Retry/Ignore dialog will show up. If I have t1.join there, then it would not show this dialog.  What causes this problem?

I put Linux tag because I finally will port this project to Linux.  So I hope this solution is not going to cause Linux problem.

Comment: Destroying a `joinable()` `std::thread` results in a call to `std::terminate`.

Comment: thank you, I found that too.